# PHP data insert with preconditions

Tags: php, insert

I need a script to generate hourly PSI Data that is logical. (data between hours can only +-5 or remain the same). Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: You should do your homework first and then ask for tips or someone to do it for you

Comment: $min=60;
$max =120;
$psi = rand($min,$max);

Comment: That's what I have. It can only generate random data.. how do I add the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

This will generate a random `$psi` value and after each loop it will generate a new random `$psi` value between +/- 5 of previous `$psi` value

```
$min = 60; 
$max = 120; 
$psi = rand($min,$max);
$stop_loop = false;
while(!$stop_loop) {
    $min = $psi - 5;
    $max = $psi + 5;
    $psi = rand($min, $max);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry , but what i need is actually for psi change in the range from -5 to +5. like +5, +4 , +3, +2 etc.

Comment: It changes in that range. So you will get a value of lets say 80 when you do the first random. When you get inside the loop the random range will be between 80-5 and 80+5. Lets say it will random 83. On the next loop it will random between 83-5 and 83+5 and so on.

Comment: while(true) means that it will continue looping right? How to make it such that it won't keep looping?

Comment: Add a condition inside the lopp to break the loop. See the answer edit

Comment: Thanks yo so much. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Sorry, i have one more question. If lets say i have 3 locations all with hourly basis how do i generate them accordingly? as of now i can only generate hourly time from let's say 1/10/14- 30/10/14 with three locations randomly filled in between. I need to have location 1 , location 2 and 3 . all with dates from 1/10 - 30/10.

Comment: Sorry i have encountered this problem while adding the loop. "Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\insertpsi.php on line 45"